# How to display server output in web page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, web

For example, in Jenkins, when you run a job, you can see the output of the job which is being ran in remote server in Jenkins's webpage, realtime.

In fact, I am writing a web page, when user click `run`, a program in server will be ran, and I would like to show the output(stdout/stderr) of the program to the user in this web page.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket can solve your problem.

> Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication.

Please refer more detail here:

https://socket.io/